# Attached property is not binding in label visibility in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have used attached property in my application to hide the label,

```
public class LabelExtension
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ShowTimeStampProperty =
        BindableProperty.CreateAttached("ShowTimeStamp", typeof(bool), typeof(LabelExtension), false);

    public static bool GetShowTimeStamp(BindableObject view)
    {
        return (bool)view.GetValue(ShowTimeStampProperty);
    }

    public static void SetShowTimeStamp(BindableObject view, bool value)
    {
        view.SetValue(ShowTimeStampProperty, value);
    }
}
```

View side binding is done like this,

```
<Label IsVisible="{Binding  Path=extension:LabelExtension.ShowTimeStamp}"/>
```

But label is still visible how to achieve this, please anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you choose another simpler way like `isVisible = "{Binding value}"`

```
bool _value;
public bool value{
    get { return _value; }
    set
    {
        _value = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a typical example related to Attached Property and Behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/attached

Answer (score 0):

> An attached property is a special type of bindable property, defined
>   in one class but attached to other objects, and recognizable in XAML
>   as an attribute that contains a class and a property name separated by
>   a period.

It is **not recommend** to binding an attached property.

An attached property can define a `propertyChanged delegate` that will be executed when the value of the property changes, such as when the property is set on a control. In your case, you can make your label Visible or not in the `propertyChanged delegate` but there is no need.

You can use `NotifyPropertyChanged();` as `Huy Nguyen` mentioned in his answer. Or you can create a model inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and binding a property in the model to control label's visibility.

Refer : [data-binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/)

[bindable-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)